# Can this DC-DC converter be connected directly

Tags: dc-dc-converter

Should [this](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/685/ds_BCM4414xG0F4440yzz-1129834.pdf) converter be also connected through SCL, SDA and other pins, or can it work just with input and output connected (standalone)?

Answer (score 0):

Since it has no programming pins other than one for its own address I think *everything* is set thru pmbus. How would you set, for example, the output voltage otherwise?

Study the datasheet, PMbus is not difficult to use anyway

Comment: but is has fixed 16:1 ratio - so it maybe should work "out of the box"? - connecting a device just to control this converter would be waste of space, money and time.

Comment: In that case, surely, a simpler converter without digital control would save even more money?